# Adding products to cart after creating new customer

Tags: product, cart, price, addtocart

I have a controller that calls a helper. The idea is that the controller passes an array of data that the helper will use to create a new customer and then add items to the cart.

This is the controller function

```
 public function makeCustomerAction(){
    $_POST['cdata'] = array(
        'login' => '1jason@email.co.uk',
        'password' => 'password',
        'billing-firstname' => 'jason',
        'billing-lastname' => 'vogel',
        'billing-city' => 'london',
        'billing-region_id' => 'UK',
        'billing-region' => '',
        'billing-postcode' => 'W33ffdN',
        'billing-country_id' => 'UK',
        'billing-telephone' => '213',
        'shipping-firstname' => 'jason',
        'shipping-lastname' => 'jason',
        'shipping-city' => 'London',
        'shipping-region_id' => 'UK',
        'shipping-region' => '',
        'shipping-country_id' => 'UK',
        'shipping-telephone' => '123123123',
    );

    $_POST['pdata'] = array(
        '0' => '5053484466973',
        '1' => '5053484201505',
    );
    $customerId = thomas_Mto_Helper_Create::makeCustomer($_POST['cdata']);
    thomas_Mto_Helper_Create::addAddress($_POST['cdata'], $customerId);
    thomas_Mto_Helper_Create::addToCart($_POST['pdata']);

    }
```

This is the helper

```
 class thomas_Mto_Helper_Create extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
  {

public function makeCustomer($customerDetails){

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    //$customer  = new Mage_Customer_Model_Customer();
    $password = $customerDetails['password'];
    $email = $customerDetails['login'];
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    //Zend_Debug::dump($customer->debug()); exit;
    if(!$customer->getId()) {
        $customer->setEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname($customerDetails['billing-firstname']);
        $customer->setLastname($customerDetails['billing-lastname']);
        $customer->setPassword($password);
    }
    try {
        $customer->save();
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
    }

    return $customer->getId();
}

public function addAddress($customerDetails, $customerId){
    //Build billing and shipping address for customer, for checkout
    $billingAddress = array (
        'firstname' => $customerDetails['billing-firstname'],
        'lastname' => $customerDetails['billing-lastname'],
        'street' => array (
            '0' => $customerDetails['billing-street0'],
            '1' => $customerDetails['billing-street1'],
        ),
        'city' => $customerDetails['billing-city'],
        'region_id' => $customerDetails['billing-region_id'],
        'region' => $customerDetails['billing-region'],
        'postcode' => $customerDetails['billing-postcode'],
        'country_id' => $customerDetails['billing-country_id'], 
        'telephone' => $customerDetails['billing-telephone'],
    );

    $shippingAddress = array (
        'firstname' => $customerDetails['shipping-firstname'],
        'lastname' => $customerDetails['shipping-lastname'],
        'street' => array (
            '0' => $customerDetails['shipping-street0'],
            '1' => $customerDetails['shipping-street1'],
        ),
        'city' => $customerDetails['shipping-city'],
        'region_id' => $customerDetails['shipping-region_id'],
        'region' => $customerDetails['shipping-region'],
        'postcode' => $customerDetails['shipping-postcode'],
        'country_id' => $customerDetails['shipping-country_id'], 
        'telephone' => $customerDetails['shipping-telephone'],
    );
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
        if($i<1){
            $_custom_address = $billingAddress;
            $billing = '1';
            $shipping = '';
        }else{
            $_custom_address = $shippingAddress;
            $billing = '';
            $shipping = '1';
        }

        $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
        $customAddress = new Mage_Customer_Model_Address();
        $customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
                    // ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling($billing)
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping($shipping)
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        try {
            $customAddress->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public function addToCart($products){
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    foreach ($products as $key => $sku) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->getFirstItem();

        $product->load($product->getId());
        // $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

        try {
            $cart->addProduct($product);
            $cart->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
        // unset($product);
    }
    $cart->save();
}
}
```

So far it creates the customer and for the most part it adds the products to the cart.

- The issue is that if I try to add two products sometimes it only adds the first (never the second if it excludes any).
- Another issue is that in some cases the price comes up at zero when looking at the customers cart from the admin section (I've noticed this is most likely to happen if the customer does not exist prior to running the script).
- The other issue is when I log into the frontend with the new customer credentials in some cases there is nothing in the cart even when the cart looks to be populated in the admin section. Also the price is nearly always incorrect in the frontend. Either listing the product as zero or the full price.

NOTE - all of these issues only apply to my script. There is no problems with the general functionality of the site.

Comment: Thomas Ryan,you need to page refresh after logged in after that cart added may add working..

Comment: what actually happens to make that work? Maybe I can replicate the process without page refresh because I'm running it through ajax and I'd prefer to just have one call.

Comment: then used two ajax call first one doing customer  register second one  add product in cart

Comment: then second ajax must trigger after get reponse from first one

Comment: it need for session  set at  magento

Comment: still only adding one product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amit Bera was on the right track when he mentioned page refresh.

To get this to work I started by adding the new customer and address in one call. It still wasn't behaving correctly with the products but I found when I added each product within an individual call it worked.

So the end result meant that I had to loop around the ajax call for each product that I wanted to add to the cart. Then in that call just add one product and go back to a new ajax call before adding the next.